# Microsoft SQL Server. Error 233. Provider: SSL Provider without disable TLS 1.1 and 1.2

Tags: sql-server, windows, ssl, tls1.2

We have enabled tls 1.1 and tls 2.0 on our server since most of our clients are using this encryption. However, since this change our SQL server 2014 refuse to log in with the error :

```
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 233)
```

I did look at this topic : [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44067698/how-to-solve-microsoft-sql-server-error-233-provider-ssl-provider) however we cannot disabled tls 1.1 and 1.2 since we actually need it on our server.

**Note** Running Windows 2012 R2  that we have the latest version SP2 Installed (12.0.5579.0), all the provider TCP, Shared and Named are enabled and all SQL server services is running.

**Update**

We do have error in the event :

```
An TLS 1.2 connection request was received from a remote client application, but none of the cipher suites supported by the client application are supported by the server. The SSL connection request has failed.
```

We do have a SHA256 cert

Comment: It sounds like something is failing to start internally. Is there anything in the event log? If it is TLS support, could you e.g. upgrade to the latest SQL Server ?

Comment: We did check and  we do have some errors